# Set Content Security Policy of an iframe?

Tags: iframe, user-agent, content-security-policy, webcrypto-api, subresource-integrity

Is there a way for the consumer website (eg nytimes.com) to assure itself that an iframe it loads will NOT be able to communicate with ahy servers, and only has access to postMessage? This can be done from the server hosting the iframe’s document. But I don’t want to have to trust that server.

Here is what I need this for: I want to store non-extractable asymnetic keys using subtle-crypto, load some static HTML with inline JS that was audited by third parties, I am sure that’s what was loaded using an SRI, and finally pass some data usibg postMessage to it, and CLOSE THE DOOR in that sanbox by overriding postMessag, to GUARANTEE to the user of the user-agent that any data decrypted and displayed from that point on cannot be leaked to anyone else (assuming the user agent follows web standards).

How will the USER know they can trust the iframe? Because the iframe would display some familiar string they chose, decrypted by the same private key, after the door is closed. Since it’s not extractable, no server can decrypt it so it must be the audited safe HTML + JS environment trusted by the user.

But how can the user, and the embedding site, verify and be SURE what the content security policy of the iframe is??

Comment: The user would only have to trust the domain of the iframe during registration, when they chose their special phrase to reassure themselves. This phrase would also appear on keyboard focus in an input, saying it’s safe to type, to prevent clickjacking.

Comment: You may ask why I need to have a Content Security Policy if the code was audited and loaded with an SRI. First of all so I can receive and run arbitrary code inside that environment. And second of all because the user needs to trust the environment, and the consumer site could have cheated the user and loaded something else. The user needs to know the DOOR IS CLOSED before they enter a passcode to unlock the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out HTML has the “http-equiv” meta tag which can set the Content Security Policy of that HTML document. And the enclosing site can use SRI to make sure it is loading a document it previously audited.

So that takes care of trust by the enclosing site. However I am not sure how a user of a mainstream browser can verify

- The loaded iframe document is the same as a document loaded before (subresource integrity visible for user)
- The loaded iframe document has the right Content Security Policy, unless they View Source.

Perhaps someone can address the two things above, how can the user trust the loaded document and that the door is CLOSED. The Web makes it very hard to not have to trust servers on the internet to collude and change up code anytime.